# How to display the below given data row wise?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, html-table

How to change below html to required format as in below image when I get dynamic data?

```
<div id="pdfTable" #pdfTable style="display: none;">
    <table class="table table-borderless mb-0" style="font-size:14px;margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td style="border:0"><b>Rating Scale: </b></td>
                <td style="border:0" colspan="4"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor='let rating of ratings'>
                <td colspan="5" style="border:0"><b>{{rating.ratingId}}</b><span>.
                    </span><b>{{rating.ratingName}}</b></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Required Format**

[image: Required Format]

**What I am getting from above html**

[image: What I am getting from above html]

Change html to format which is Shown in Required Format image dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current markup creates a new `<tr>` (table row) for each rating. But your design shows you want two cells:

- one with *"Rating Scale:"*
- one with the actual ratings.

In the second column, I used a [CSS columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) layout, with two columns.
The rest are details.

**Template**:

```html
<div id="pdfTable" #pdfTable style="display: none">
  <table
    class="table table-borderless mb-0"
    style="font-size: 14px; margin-bottom: 15px"
  >
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Rating Scale:</td>
        <td>
          <div class="ratings">
            <div *ngFor="let rating of ratings">
              <div>{{ rating.ratingName }}.</div>
              <div>{{ rating.ratingName }}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**SCSS**:

```scss
#pdfTable {
    border: 2px solid black;
  td {
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    &:first-child {
      vertical-align: top;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
  }
  .ratings {
    columns: 2;
    & > div {
      font-weight: bold;
      break-inside: avoid;
      display: flex;
      & > div:first-child {
        flex: 0 0 2rem;
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 0.5rem;
      }
      & > div:last-child {
        flex-grow: 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You might need to tweak the CSS a bit in terms of margins/paddings, according to your project.

---

Rough demo of the output (just the HTML and CSS, no angular):

```css
#pdfTable {
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#pdfTable td {
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#pdfTable td:first-child {
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#pdfTable .ratings {
  columns: 2;
}
#pdfTable .ratings > div {
  font-weight: bold;
  break-inside: avoid;
  display: flex;
}
#pdfTable .ratings > div > div:first-child {
  flex: 0 0 2rem;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
}
#pdfTable .ratings > div > div:last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="pdfTable" #pdfTable>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Rating Scale:</td>
        <td>
          <div class="ratings">
            <div>
              <div>5.</div>
              <div>Outstanding</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div>4.</div>
              <div>Excellent-exceeds expectations</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div>3.</div>
              <div>Competent-acceptable proficiency</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div>2.</div>
              <div>Below average - does not meet requirements</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div>1.</div>
              <div>Unable to determine or not applicable to this candidate</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```